# RxJS: merge with single emit on completion

Tags: rxjs

Is there an RxJS factory function (or more generally a pattern) to merge several others together, but only *emit once* when all of them have completed?

The use case I want this for, is to wait for several parallel operations, and then do something else, once they complete. For promises this can be done like this:

```
Promise.all(A, B, C).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

For observables, the best I've come up with yet is

```
merge(A, B, C).pipe(takeLatest(1)).subscribe(() => console.log('done'));
```

This doesn't account for `A`, `B`, and `C` being empty, though. And it doesn't provide a deterministic value to the subscriber. Isn't there a simple built-in solution for this use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin). This operator emits once all its given observables are completed.

```js
const { Observable, of, forkJoin } = rxjs;

const obs1$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next('obs1$ - value 1');
  subscriber.next('obs1$ - value 2');
  subscriber.complete();
})
const obs2$ = of('obs2$');
const obs3$ = of('obs3$');

const result$ = forkJoin(
  obs1$,
  obs2$,
  obs3$
);

result$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! `forkJoin` is exactly what I was looking for. I don't see why I should apply `last()` to the arguments, though. `forkJoin` already returns the last emitted elements, doesn't it?

Comment: Absolutely true. Sorry - I will update the answer :)